# Postgres: which index to add

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, window-functions

I have a table mainly used by this query (only 3 columns are in use here, `meter`, `timeStampUtc` and `createdOnUtc`, but there are other in the table), which starts to take too long:

```sql
select
    rank() over (order by mr.meter, mr."timeStampUtc") as row_name
  , max(mr."createdOnUtc") over (partition by mr.meter, mr."timeStampUtc") as "createdOnUtc"
from
    "MeterReading" mr
where
    "createdOnUtc" >= '2021-01-01'
order by row_name
;
```

(this is the minimal query to show my issue. It might not make too much sense on its own, or could be rewritten)

I am wondering which index (or other technique) to use to optimise this particular query.

A basic index on `createdOnUtc` helps already.

I am mostly wondering about those 2 windows functions. They are very similar, so I factorised them (named window with thus identical `partition by` and `order by`), it had no effect. Adding an index on `meter, "timeStampUtc"` had no effect either (query plan unchanged).

Is there no way to use an index on those 2 columns inside a window function?

Edit - explain analyze output: using the createdOnUtc index

```
Sort  (cost=8.51..8.51 rows=1 width=40) (actual time=61.045..62.222 rows=26954 loops=1)
   Sort Key: (rank() OVER (?))
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 2874kB
   ->  WindowAgg  (cost=8.46..8.50 rows=1 width=40) (actual time=18.373..57.892 rows=26954 loops=1)
         ->  WindowAgg  (cost=8.46..8.48 rows=1 width=40) (actual time=18.363..32.444 rows=26954 loops=1)
               ->  Sort  (cost=8.46..8.46 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=18.353..19.663 rows=26954 loops=1)
                     Sort Key: meter, "timeStampUtc"
                     Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 2874kB
                     ->  Index Scan using "MeterReading_createdOnUtc_idx" on "MeterReading" mr  (cost=0.43..8.45 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.068..8.059 rows=26954 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: ("createdOnUtc" >= '2021-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)
 Planning Time: 0.082 ms
 Execution Time: 63.698 ms
```

Comment: I don't think there is much you can do apart from that index, unless you want to get into fancy stuff like filtered indexes.

Comment: An index over all columns involved might speed things up, because it could become an index only scan: CREATE INDEX ON "MeterReading"("createdOnUtc", mr.meter, "timeStampUtc"); Could you show the results from EXPLAIN ANALYZE ?

Comment: @FrankHeikens thanks - I had 2 indexes (createOnUtc and (meter, timeStampUtc)). Only one was used, which makes sense. Replacing those 2 by one 3-columns index, as you suggest, does not change the cost in my example, but it indeed becomes an index only scan. Sounds hard to beat.

Comment: If speed is critical and most queries access current data (e.g. the current month as in your example), you may want to consider partitioning the table. Thus the queries would deal with much smaller data.

Comment: It is hard to believe that 63ms "take too long" for returning 27,000 rows.  What the heck are you doing with 27,000 rows once you have them that 63ms is too long?  Especially considering that the only parameter to your query is one that would seem to change only once per month.

Comment: Does the plan you posted reflect reality, or is just an artefact of having run it with a hot cache?  The initial selection and sorting of the data takes less then a third of the total time, so that is the most time you could knock off it using an absolutely perfect index for selecting and sorting (which doesn't exist for this case anyway)

Comment: @jjanes this was with the createdOnUtc index used indeed, to show it was used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there no way to use an index on those 2 columns inside a window function?

That is correct; a window function cannot use an index, as the work **only** on what otherwise would be the final result, all data selection has already finished. From the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/tutorial-window.html).

> The rows considered by a window function are those of the “virtual
> table” produced by the query's FROM clause as filtered by its WHERE,
> GROUP BY, and HAVING clauses if any. For example, a row removed
> because it does not meet the WHERE condition is not seen by any window
> function. A query can contain multiple window functions that slice up
> the data in different ways using different OVER clauses, but they all
> act on the same collection of rows defined by this virtual table.

The purpose of an index is to speed up the creation of that "virtual table". Applying an index would just slow things down: the data is already in memory. Scanning it is orders of magnitude faster any any index.