# Postgres crosstab predicate pushdown

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, crosstab

TLDR: are filter on a view pushed down to crosstab()?

Long story:
I have this view:

```
create view v as 
  with pivot as (
    select * from crosstab("bigquery", "tiny static query") as a(
       row_name -- crosstab row name
     , createdOnUtc -- extra column
     , cat1, cat2, cat3, cat4 -- multiple categories
     )
  )
  select * from pivot -- the select actually does more than that, the cte is warranted
```

The "big query" inside crosstab looks like:

```
select
    rank() over (order by mr.meter, mr."timeStampUtc") as row_name
  , max(mr."createdOnUtc") over (partition by mr.meter, mr."timeStampUtc") as "createdOnUtc"
from
    "MeterReading" mr
where
    "createdOnUtc" >= '2021-01-01'
order by row_name
```

And is as optimised as possible I think ([previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65943733/postgres-which-index-to-add)).

The view is used roughly as: `select * from v where createdOnUtc > 'date'` with this query plan:

```
Function Scan on crosstab a  (cost=0.00..12.50 rows=333 width=68) (actual time=21475.128..21475.129 rows=0 loops=1)
   Filter: ("createdOnUtc" >= '2021-01-12 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 111926
```

Which is kinda expected because crosstab is a black box for the analyser.

If I run the crosstab big query on its own with a filter on createdOnUtc, I can see that the filter uses an index. I cannot confirm it within the actual crosstab() function, could not find anything in the doc, and I have the feeling that it's not used.

Could someone confirm/infirm my suspiscion? Note that I am using PG 12, so the CTE is not a fence any more.

The reason for my question is that I am running this query on a small server, and it gets oom'ed more often than not.

Comment: I find using a filtered aggregation way easier to maintain than using the `crosstab` function. And that typically opens up way more possibilities for the optimizer

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name agree about the uppercase identifiers, but sadly it is to follow a model which requires uppercases, it's out of my hands :( the silver lining is that the queries mostly come from ORM, so I do not have to care about them.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name good tip with the `filter` aggregate. Would there be performance drawback?

Comment: I would assume the pivot using a filtered aggregate would be more efficient than the crosstab solution (no black box involved, and in the end it's more or less the same query)